A movie about wichcraft, a secret cult and a girl trying to find and save her missing mother
I'm looking for a film that is about a normal teenage girl with long blonde hair who has a normal life and later learns that her mother is missing and no one can find her. Later in the school she learns from a friend that she has powers and that she is a witch like her mother. Later she jumps from the balcony and turns into a crow (black bird) and tries to find and save her missing mother.
At the same time, political choices are made and the sect of the secession  bus is exploded and publicly presented as a terrorist attack, the secret sect attempts to set up their man as mayor of the city.
At the end, the girl destroys the sect and saves her mother, but in fact, she's not really her mother but a clone who has taken her mother's look (one of the witches took her mother's look to survive) .
The film was 2 or 3 parts. I watched it on TV. Language is English, it's in color. I think It's from 4-5 years ago (2012-2013). 

When did you watch this movie? What language? Color or black-white? Subtitles/ Dubbing? Can you describe these people any better?

What does "the sect of the secession of a bus is exploded" mean?

...and do you mean "clone" and not "clown"?

Thanks for clarifying a crow is a black bird.

This is some serious downvoting here!

I hope someone can recognize it. In the mean time you can try IMDB keywords using keywords like this. Also a time frame might help (it was in colors, but does it look from 2 years ago or 20?).

The movie is something like Innocents 2014.
